# Why does my .NET 5.0 application log to an 'npm' console window in VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I recently switched from building a project in VS Code to Visual Studio 2019.

In VS Code, the output was routed to the Output window in VS Code.

In Visual Studio 2019, the output goes to a console prompt titled "npm" which must remain open otherwise the program terminates. This happens whether I am debugging the program or not.

How can I prevent this behavior?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the **IIS Express** launch profile within Visual Studio to run your application instead. Using this profile would not open a separate debugger console while running your application.

[image: IIS Express launch profile]

IIS Express is usually the default profile used when launching an app from Visual Studio. If not, you can create and configure a launch profile yourself.

The steps are detailed in the following articles:

- [Development and launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson)
- [launchSettings.json & Debug Profile in ASP.NET Core](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/launchsettings-json-debug-profile-in-asp-net-core/)